# Tomcat server in Eclipse : the war in target directory is not deployed correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, m2eclipse

I build my project with Maven (command -> mvn clean install -Pdev) to generate the war file for *dev* environment. The value of the variable backdoor is equal to true with the profile *dev*

---

**dev.properties**

backdoor=true

---

I have another propertie file where I use the variable backdoor

---

**configuraton.properties**
app.open.backdoor=${backdoor}

---

The project is built succesfuly.

In Eclipse, I created an instance of Tomcat server to run the web application. I added the war file and I run the server.

No errors in the log.

When I try to access the web application, I only see only blank page.

I decided to launch the server in debug mode to inspect the value of the variable **backdoor**, it remaind equal to ${backdoor}

I use *Resource.getBundle()* to retrieve the value of *app.open.backdoor*

I unzip the war file to see the content of configuration.properties. The value of the variable
app.open.backdoor is set correctly to ****true****

---

**configuraton.properties**
app.open.backdoor=**true**

---

Why Tomcat is not using the value *true* in the configuration.properties of the war file, instead of ${backdoor} ?

I try to clean, publish the server but no success.

Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the web ap was connected to a wrong database.